# How to enable haptic feedback on button view

Tags: android, vibration

I want to add haptic feedback to my application's buttons and control them programmatically to show button state (enabled and disabled).
The default haptic feedback setter works only for long press. How can i make it work for simple button clicks.

And is there a way to have haptic feedback on events like touch move?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here is an answer, though it might not be the best implementation:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private View myView;
    private Vibrator myVib;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        //myView can be any type of view, button, etc.
        myView = (View) this.findViewById(R.id.myView);
        myView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        myVib.vibrate(50);
        //add whatever you want after this
    }
}
```

Don't forget, you also need to add the "android.permission.VIBRATE" permission to the program's manifest. You can do so by adding the following to the "AndroidManifest.xml" file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: If you place the 'this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);' inside of a button's onClickListener, then 'this' refers to the button itself which does not have the method getSystemService.  Use this instead: 'getApplicationContext().getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);'

Comment: you can't always use getApplicationContext() inside an onClickListener

Answer (score 124):

**UPDATE ON DECEMBER 24TH 2019:**

The view must be enabled Haptic function by:

1. Add `android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"` in xml.
2. Or use `view.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);` in code

   *(Cited from Ivan Chau)*

However, one more thing to take into consideration is to enable Haptic Setting in virtual devices. This is annoying sometimes, so we have some flags come to help (which will ignore these enable Setting somehow):

```
view.performHapticFeedback(
    HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY, 
    HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING  // Ignore device's setting. Otherwise, you can use FLAG_IGNORE_VIEW_SETTING to ignore view's setting.
);
```

---

An example to Mayra is, for run the Haptic Feedback is by using this code.

```
View view = findViewById(...)
view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
```

And this line of code can easy be include in you onclick action.
The good part with this is you do not need to set a permission in the AndroidManifest
(I do not need this on SdkVersion "7" (2.1 or 2.3 is 7 ))

Also note, in my code here, this will only be running if the user has enabled Haptic Feedback as global. 
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html for alway use it.

Comment: Add `android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"` in button xml or use `btn.setHapticFeedbackEnabled( true );` in code

Comment: @IvanChau I tried putting in your code, to no avail.  Is it because I need to specify a button and not a view?

Answer (score 32):

View has a performHapticFeedback function, which should allow you to perform it whenever you want, i.e., on an OnClick listener.

Comment: I added the following code in the onClick method of the onClickListener but it didn't work


btn_left     .performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_VIEW_SETTING);


Im not really sure how this flag works

Comment: Did you set haptic feedback to enabled?  Per the documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback(int)  this is necessary to get any haptic feedback to play.  I'm not sure about that constant, did you try using VIRTUAL_KEY?

Comment: HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY is not available. Im currently using Android 1.5_r2
And yes the haptic feedback is enabled for the buttons in the xml itself.

Still no luck

Comment: Didn't work for me until I added the second flag `HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING`, like in Hamid Vakilian's answer below.

Comment: Won't it work without click? Actually I'm trying to use haptic feedback on success of failure response of an API call and that is working fine in Google Pixel device but not in samsung.

Answer (score 20):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY, HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING);
```

a straightforward approach you can use in an activity.

Comment: Superb. Really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers please make sure that "Vibration Feedback" option is enabled from your device settings

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering is there any reference to this setting?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to preform haptic feedback when a dialog fragment opened. The existing answers to this question weren't working. I had to wrap in `postDelayed` to get it to work.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    preformHapticFeedback()
}

private fun preformHapticFeedback() {
    val delay = 1L
    requireView().postDelayed(
        {
            requireView().performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY)
        },
        delay
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes this was also my case.  It worked with postdelayed() but do you have an idea why this could be.