# Android Vibrate on touch?

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am trying to make my device vibrate when I touch an object on Screen. I am using this code:

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 
 v.vibrate(300);
```

with the permission in the manifest file but I don't seem to get any results.
 Any suggestions? Also, my hardware supports vibrate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

please try this :

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator)   getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vb.vibrate(100);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and add this permission to manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: it works fine I think you implement onTouch method on wrong widget please check again.because their is no problem with vibration code.

Comment: This is nice, but when user continue moving finger, it will keep vibrating - not a good user experience - See my answer below which solves this

Answer (score 27):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228151/how-to-enable-haptic-feedback-on-button-view/13152567#13152567), you can perform haptic feedback (vibrate) without asking for any extra permissions. Look at [`performHapticFeedback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback(int)) method.

```
View view = findViewById(...)
view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
```

Note: I have not tested this code.

Comment: I find that this one is kind of weak. Are there any stronger touch vibrations?

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for avoiding additional permissions.

Answer (score 2):

This will vibrate once, when user touches view (will not keep vibrating when user sliding his finger on the view!):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION_MS);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And as Ramesh said, allow permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for `kotlin`,

```
val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
vibrator.vibrator(durationInMilliSeconds)
```

and for Android-O and newer,

```
val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(vibrationDuration, vibrationAmplitude)
vibrator.vibrator(vibrationEffect)
```

while to cancel vibration,

```
vibrate.cancel()
```

you also need to add permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

working for me `kotlin ext fun`

for the haptic effect, vibro has 5 milliseconds!! (`SHORT_HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION`)

```
fun Context.performHapticFeedback() {
    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
        vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(SHORT_HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION))
    }
}

private const val SHORT_HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION = 5L
```

usage

```
addOnItemTouchListener(ItemTouchListener { position, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    context.performHapticFeedback()  
                }  
            })
```

permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

good luck ✌ :))