# Button view haptic feedback only works on own device?

Tags: android, button

Used the following:

[How to enable haptic feedback on button view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228151/how-to-enable-haptic-feedback-on-button-view)

```
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private View myView;
    private Vibrator myVib;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        //myView can be any type of view, button, etc.
        myView = (View) this.findViewById(R.id.myView);
        myView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        myVib.vibrate(50);
        //add whatever you want after this
    }
}
```

> The error occurs on the following line: myView.setOnClickListener(this);

Button haptic feedback vibration only works on personal device and not on devices that download from the Google Play Store.

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

Comment: What's the error? Can you post the exception stack?

Comment: It just doesn't provide haptic feedback on other devices.